# Basic Wordpress header conditional

Tags: wordpress, header, conditional-statements

Does anyone know why this conditional code below won't pull up a "header-events.php" file for the "/events" page on my Wordpress site? Instead its pulling up the general "header.php" file.

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
elseif ( is_page( 'events' ) ) :
    get_header( 'events' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

Here is my "header-events.php" code below. Basically I'm just trying to add an "events" class to the header element that has a different background image. Since it's loading the "page" class for the header in the rendered code I know it's pulling the general header.php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alike" rel="stylesheet"> 

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="events">
        <div class="nav-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          LITTLE ENGLAND FARM
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/faith">Faith</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/family">Family</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/farm">Farm</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/sarah-creek-house">Sarah's Creek House</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/images/logo-e.png" /></a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          VISIT THE MERCANTILE
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/mercantile">Mercantile</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/events">Events</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/equipva">EquipVA</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
      <!-- <h1>WELCOME</h1> -->
    </header>
```

Pulling from the bottom of this Codex page - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/.

Here is the link I'm testing - http://new.littleenglandfarm.com/events/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: too broad. where you put the code provided? what page you're calling? provide `header-events.php` file

Comment: 1. Are you confident that "if" condition is firing? Have you _proven_ it? 2. Where do you have this snippet? 3. How are you determining that the `header-events.php` is NOT being included / loaded?

Comment: Thanks @Samvel Aleqsanyan and cale_b. I just edited my original post to include the header file and additional comments.